# UITableViewCell indentation not in edit mode

Tags: iphone, uitableview

When you enter editing mode on a grouped-style UITableView, the cells indent to show the editing control (if you aren't sure what I mean, see this picture (editing mode) https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpD1Z.png and this (non-editing mode) https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Oyd.png).

I am trying to manually indent a cell when the tableView is not in editing mode.  I tried the indentationLevel property, but that just moves the text further to the right inside the cell and doesn't actually change the cell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I can't access `imgur.com` right now so this is my best guess.

I guess you add all subviews to `cell.view` instead of `cell.contentView`. You should try adding them to `cell.contentView`.

If you subclass the UITableViewCell, you should override `layoutSubviews` to adjust all subviews according to `cell.contentView.bounds`.

Hope this works.

Comment: Good catch! I added as subviews to self rather than to self.contentView -- switching to contentView fixed it for me. :)

Comment: This is how real indentation works in edit mode.  The framework just resizes the contentView.